# Google Sheets spreadsheet automatically aligns entire page to the right most column and won't allow any other position

Tags: google-sheets

When I open any spreadsheet in  Google sheets, the entire page automatically aligns to the right most column.  And, when I use the slider to move it to the left, within 2 seconds of releasing the mouse button the page automatically slides back to the right.  If I use the left arrow button to slide the page to the left, it actually fights me and won't allow it to get beyond several columns before it starts shifting back to the right.

This started 2 days ago and I don't know if it was while I was working in a spreadsheet of if it was upon opening a spreadsheet.  Here is what I've tried and observed . . .

- It happens with any spreadsheet and even when I open a spreadsheet from my work email
- All spreadsheets have this same problem.
- I can't find any option in the menu bar that would have done this.
- I can't find any topics on this issue with a google search (what pulls up are issues related to cell alignment and this issue is the entire page's alignment).
- I have shifted margins in the print screen window and this does not help.
- I have cleared all browsing data for all time in Google Chrome
- This problem is not an issue in Google Docs
- The only remedy is logging into a different computer and then Sheets works fine.

Please help !!!

Sam

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). That sounds like a browser or system extension issue. Try opening a spreadsheet in a private or incognito window, or in another browser such as Opera, Firefox or Safari. Look through your system to identify possibly interfering extensions such as [Caffeine](https://zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/).

Comment: Exact copy of [Google sheets automatically shifts spreadsheets to the right](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/179395368) that has an answer.

Answer (score 1):

OP's message at the [Google Sheets Support Forum](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/179395368):

> I recently found out it was my mouse.  I hadn't suspected that as I wasn't noticing problems with any other google apps or programs in general.  But when I disconnected the wireless USB and reconnected it, the problem immediately was resolved.